# Alternative Notepad++ Shortcut Mapper plugin?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a Shortcut Mapper plugin for Notepad++ that offers the following functionality? (This functionality is currently not present in Shortcut Mapper)

a) Quickly search through all shortcuts/commands to see if there is already a shortcut present for the command - this could be achieved by some 'search' functionality or by being able to sort the shortcuts list by 'command' or by 'shortcuts'

b) Give a warning in case a shortcut entered against a command is already present.

PS. While writing this question, I found a [list of default shortcuts](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts), which helps somewhat!

Comment: sorting what? what is the `file format` ? I don't see any "sorting" shortcut in the Shortcut Mapper...

Comment: Most Shortcut Managers allow you the capability of sorting either by the command or by the shortcut by clicking on the column header of the shortcuts list

Comment: this is not the case here. In version 5.9.8 I don't see any kind of sorting.

Comment: I'm not talking about a 'sorting' shortcut. I'm saying the shortcuts cannot be sorted.

Comment: Why is the question closed? Is this not a valid 'programming' related question? I've rephrased the question if that helps.

Comment: the reason for which the moderators decided to close the question - is not valid TMHO. But I'm afraid that there's not much you can do in regards.

Comment: the damn hell they closed the question? non-constructive my ass! the question is perfectly constructive. it may be off-topic for SO. but the reason they gave? moderators amaze me more and more here. it looks like they just cant deny themselves to moderate something. badge hunters lol